# XQUERY: selection of data using non XML columns

Tags: db2, xquery

I have DB2 table having following structure

CREATE TABLE DUMMY
(
ID CHARACTER(10) NOT NULL,
RECORD XML NOT NULL
)

I want to use XQUERY to select data in RECORD column on the basis of ID. and do some XQUERY operations on the data present in RECORD column.

eg: I want to select RECORD having ID 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `db2-fn:sqlquery` function to do this.  See the [documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/xqrfnsqq.html).